# Multiple Threads not initializing

Tags: python, priority-queue, python-multithreading

I am trying to create a priority queuing system. I have designed it and written 3 threads to do this.

The first thread takes items out of an output queue and sorts based on a priority into the correct priority queue. The second thread using a timer and variables then takes items out of the 5 priority queues and places them in the prioritised order into the input work queue where the third thread uses multiprocessing to do work to the devices in the queue.

The problem that I am having is that for some reason only the first thread is initializing. I am using the multiprocessing manager queues. My threads are spawned as shown below:

```
t_one = threading.Thread(target=self.queue_sort())
t_one.start()
t_two = threading.Thread(target=self.priorityQueue_sort())
t_two.start()
t_three = threading.Thread(target=self.priorityMultiProcess_launch())                    
t_three.start()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you aware of the Global Interpreter Lock in Python which means you won't likely get any performance boost from all this?  It seems possible that another approach would be better, but we don't know what you've considered so far.

Comment: @JohnZwinck As far as I can tell from [this documentation](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), the GIL is only an issue if he's using the C implementation (which is the most common implementation, but it isn't the only one). That having been said, I didn't know about the GIL. Wonder why they decided to cripple multithreading...

Comment: yes I am aware of the GIL, i am not really after performance boost per-say just need several threads to deal with the queuing system as a lot of it needs to happen as close to concurrent as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to call your targets in the call to `threading.Thread`. Instead, just pass references, and let the `start` method call them within the new thread:

```
t_one = threading.Thread(target=self.queue_sort)      # note, fewer parentheses
t_one.start()
t_two = threading.Thread(target=self.priorityQueue_sort)      # here too
t_two.start()
t_three = threading.Thread(target=self.priorityMultiProcess_launch)     # and here
t_three.start()
```

Comment: I was just about to post the same answer. +1

Comment: thanks thats great works like a charm. I would be intrested to know why python does not like the ()

Comment: If you use the extra parens, your methods are called *before* the thread starts, and the return value is used as `target` for the threading.Thread() call.